# Turn off gif playing/looping on excel startup

Tags: excel, gif

I have an excel sheet where I inserted a couple of gifs. I paused all the gifs and closed the excel sheet. When opening the sheet, all the gifs are playing again. I cannot find any way to stop them from automatically playing/looping on startup. Is there some other way to do this by using makros or something?

I have made an example video of the described problem:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkknN7Mp2RdDgQx1_MlDZQdwoq2k?e=YDd78O

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

its probably a little late but try this Idea.

If you create a gif, try to make the loop only one time.
So the Gif will only play once, then you have to restart it.

I think it should be possible with any Gif maker

I made also a gif with this one and selected some pics.
I put loop = 1 there in the settings.

I put the gif on excel and the gif only plays one time, then you have
to press the play button again.

So if you close and start your excel, all your Gifs will only automatically
play one time, then they stop.

Maybe it could work for you ?